# Обособление вводных конструкций

Tags: вводные-слова

**И когда такой зверь в нескольких шагах от вас откровенно пробегал дорогу, пересекал по параллели этот естественно обозначенный меридиан, и был он не в масштабе, а, что называется в натуральную величину, — масштабы смещались, зверь и впрямь почти перекрывал Косу от моря до моря.**

На мой взгляд, необходимо было обособить лишь "что называется". И тогда если мы уберем "начинку", то получится: *...и был он не в масштабе, а в натуральную величину — масштабы смещались...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем примере ошибки нет. Здесь вводная конструкция находится в начале обособленного члена предложения -  **в натуральную величину.**

Вот что говорится в справочнике Розенталя.

. Если вводное слово или вводное сочетание слов стоит в начале или в конце обособленного члена предложения, то оно не отделяется от него знаком препинания, т. е. запятые выделяют член предложения вместе с вводным словом:

1) *В одну ночь,* **должно быть из озорства,** *списком был оклеен фасад городской думы (Фад.),* ср.: *Около самой черной тучи летали перекати-поле,* **и как, должно быть,** *им было страшно (Ч.);*

*К автобусу подошла девочка,* **по сути ребенок,** ср.: После этого, **по сути,** и спрашивать об ее [Аксиньи] отношениях к Григорию было незачем (Шол.); *Студент вернул в библиотеку книгу,* **вероятно даже не прочитав ее,*** ср.:  *Небо потемнело.* **Скоро, вероятно,** пойдет дождь; *Дана достаточно ясная характеристика,* **в частности декабриста Михаила Спиридова** (Чив.), ср. На собрании вопрос, **в частности,** касался методов обучения; Что же касается русских серьезных статей, **например по социологии, по искусству и проч.,** *то я не читаю их просто из робости (Ч.)*

Answer (score 0):

И когда такой зверь в нескольких шагах от вас откровенно пробегал дорогу, пересекал по параллели этот естественно обозначенный меридиан, и был он не в масштабе, а, **что называется**, в натуральную величину, — масштабы смещались, зверь и впрямь почти перекрывал Косу от моря до моря.

**Вводное предложение** после союза А обособляется, так как **союз относится к структуре предложения** (не в масштабе, а в натуральную величину).

За долгие годы работы в Казахстане он исходил его пешком вдоль и поперек, знал степи не на глазок, а, **что называется**, на ощупь. [Л. И. Брежнев. Целина (1977)]

Примеры:

Да не простую, а, **что называется,** тематическую. [Владислав Быков, Ольга Деркач. Книга века (2000)]

Речка не шумит, а, **что называется**, гремит, да еще как! [П. К. Козлов. Географический дневник Тибетской экспедиции 1923-1926 гг. №2 (1924)]